# How to declare special XML schema (XSD) case

Tags: xml, xsd

I need your help to define a special case in XML schema:
A sequence that contains two elements: 'x' and 'y' whereas:

- `<x>` element can appear 0 to unbound times in the sequence
- `<y>` element can appear 0 to 1 time in the sequence
- `<x>` and `<y>` locations can be anywhere - that is, it is possible to have unbound times the `<x>` element and then a single `<y>` element, and then unbound times the `<x>` element.

XML examples of this problem:

### Example #1

```
<x>stuff</x>
<y>stuff</y>
<x>stuff</x>
```

### Example #2

```
<y>stuff</y>
<x>stuff</x>
<x>stuff</x>
```

### Example #3

```
<x>stuff</x> 
<x>stuff</x>
<y>stuff</y>
<x>stuff</x>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For various reasons, none of Yuval's, Mo's or davidsheldon's samples work. Here's one that
does.

```
    <xs:complexType name="myComplexType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="y" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Hello Alohci - i am curious to why my solution doesn't work. Could you please share your concerns about that?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As Alohci mentioned, my solution is incorrect. According to the spec, an element in xs:all can only appear zero or one time. Sorry for any inconvenience

I think what you want isn't a sequence. A sequence defines not only the elements but also the order. And in your case the order may change. Have you tried xs:all?

```
<xs:complexType name="myComplexType">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="y" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Another appraoch might be to make it a sequence but mark the sequence to be `maxOccurs="unbounded"`

Comment: maxOccurs="unbounded" is not allowed in a xs:all group.

Answer (score 0):

Not too complicated. Off the top of my head, it should be something like this:

```
<xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:element name="y" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Since each element in XSD is optional by default, this XSD will match the XML structure you have defined, with the `y` element appearing anywhere before, after or between the `x` elements, with a maximum occurence of 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I think it more complex then this. I have the error of:
cos-nonambig: x and x (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". 

(note that your suggestion is all under "xsd:sequence")

Do you have other idea instead?
Thanks!

Comment: Elements in XSD are not optional by default. Default is minOccurs="1". Added minOccurs="0" to each gives the problem that Oger states in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used schema, but I think sequences are your answer here.

You need to have an unbounded number of choices between (an x), or (a y followed by an x).

```
<xsd:element name="parent">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="x" type="xs:string"/>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: This does not allow the group to be a single "y" element, but does allow y-x-y-x as valid sequence which shouldn't be allowed.